# Ошибка. Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, html

В игре загадки, выдает ошибку. Прошу помочь, не могу понять, где что не так. Спасибо за помощь!

```
<script>
    var score = 0;

    function checkAnswer(inputId, answers) {
        var userAnswer = document.getElementById(inputId).value;
        userAnswer = userAnswer.toLowerCase();
            for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
                if (userAnswer == answers[i]) {
                score++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    function checkAnswer() {
        checkAnswer ("userAnswer1", "сухих");
        checkAnswer ("userAnswer2", "кошка");
        checkAnswer ("userAnswer3", "капуста");

        alert ("Вы угадали - " + score + "загадок");
    }
   
</script>

<div class="gameBox">
        <p>Каких камней нет в море?</p>
        <input type="text" id="userAnswer1">

        <p>Как написать слово «мышеловка» пятью буквами?</p>
        <input type="text" id="userAnswer2">

        <p>Сто одежек и все без застежек?"</p>
        <input type="text" id="userAnswer3">
        <br><br>
        <a href="#" class="ansBtn" onclick="checkAnswer();">Ответить</>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас обе функции названы одинаково `checkAnswer`, поэтому вторая закрепляется за этим именем и зацикливается, вызывая саму себя бесконечно. Назовите их по-разному и измените вызовы соответственно.

Например, замените:

```
    function checkAnswer() {
// ...
        <a href="#" class="ansBtn" onclick="checkAnswer();">Ответить</>
```

на:

```
    function checkAnswers() {
// ...
        <a href="#" class="ansBtn" onclick="checkAnswers();">Ответить</>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!